# How to make multiple ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 5 drop-down boxes like(Country,State,District,Town,street).
When i select country,i am loading the (state,district,town,street) belong to the country.

my question is now i am making 4 separate ajax calls for this.

```
$('#Country').change(function(){
var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
    $("#State").html(procemessage).show();
    var CountryId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '../Home/LoadStateForCountry?CountryId=' + CountryId,
        success: function (result) {
            var markup = "";
            if (result.length < 1) {
                markup = "<option value='0'>--Nothing to Select--</option>";
            } else {
                data = result;
                markup = "<option value='0'>--Select--</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].ValueId + ">" + data[x].DisplayText + "</option>";
                }
            }
            $("#State").html(markup).show();
        },
    error: function (result) { }
});
}); 

$('#Country').change(function(){
//Load district
}); 

$('#Country').change(function(){
//Load town
}); 

$('#Country').change(funstion(){
//Load street
});
```

Is it right to do like this. or is there anyway to call it at once.
I am new to MVC. so please guide me.

Comment: Are you really wanting to load every `Street` belonging to a `Country` when you select a `Country`? (ie. millions of them). Surely selecting a `Country` loads its `State`'s, then selecting a `State` loads its `District`'s etc.

Comment: Sorry, This is not the exact scenario its for an example.but i need to do something like this.

Comment: Basically, I would suggest load each of them one by one. that would be a good approach. however its afterall depend how the backend API has been designed.

Comment: It makes four separate calls. is it possible to call it in single ajax call agpt

Comment: Is you ajax call returning Json to populate the dropdowns? If so, return 4 properties containing the 4 collections and update the 4 dropdowns in the success callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use ajax call to load country state

```
$('#Country').change(funstion(){
BindStateDropDown();
BindDistrictDropDown();
BindTownDropDown();
BindStreetDropDown();
});
```

**Or else What you can do is** on call back of one ajax call you can make another ajax call
Let say on call back of LoadState you can make another ajax call to load District.

```
$.get("URLToLoadState",{CountryId:CountryId <Just a parameter>},function(data){
        BindDistrict()
});
```

And on call back of District, you can go for Town and then street.

**Or another option is,**

You can create a wrapper class for all these entities like ,

```
public class LocationModel
{
  public List<StateModel> StateList{get;set;}
  public List<DistrictModel> StateList{get;set;}
  public List<TownModel> StateList{get;set;}
  public List<StreetModel> StateList{get;set;}
}
```

And on change of Country you can get this all the collection in a single call

```
$('#Country').change(funstion(){
$.get("UrlToLoadLocations",{CountryId:CountryId},function(data){
BindStateDropDown(data.StateList);
BindStateDropDown(data.DistrictList);
BindStateDropDown(data.TownList);
BindStateDropDown(data.StreetList);
});
```

});

Comment: Is it possible to load data for all four drop-downs in single ajax call

Comment: "Or another option is,"This is what i wanted, Thanks for your help.